# How to animate css 'top' in jQuery at a certain scroll location or when an element is visible?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a scrolltotop icon that appears when the window is scrolled down a bit. The thing is when the window is scrolled to the bottom of the page it overlaps a div which I do not want.

I would like to make it so the top position of scrolltotop gets animated upwards just a bit to avoid colliding with the div when the window is scrolled all the way to the bottom

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/qn6h9qad/

jQuery:

```
    //Scroll to top animate in
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(1000).css({right:-70});

    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(1000).css({right:20});
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an extra condition to the scroll event on the window:

```
if(($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) > $('.projnav').position().top){
    $('.scrollToTop').css(bottom, 40);
}
else{
    $('.scrollToTop').css(bottom, 20);
}
```

To make the animation smooth just add:

```
.scrollToTop{
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/qn6h9qad/5/

Comment: Cool this works, is there a way to make it animate to the position instead of jumping?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Scroll to top animate in
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300) {
        $('.scrollToTop').stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000)
        .css({right:-70, bottom:"20px"});

    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(1000)
        .css({right:20, bottom:"40px"});
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1000);
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qn6h9qad/4/

Comment: There is a problem when you scroll up and down, since 1.5 is bigger than .75, at some point the `$('.scrollToTop')` will be up the windows ;)

Comment: after reaching the bottom, if you scroll upwards again its getting messed up

Comment: @guest271314: But in this case you don't need jQuery to do this, you could do it changing the `bottom: 40px;` in `.scrollToTop`